# How do I style the navbar and the rest of the HTML separately? When I try to do them on the same page it always ends in disaster

Tags: html, css, navbar, margin

When I fix the navbar perfectly, the rest of the HTML page is screwed up. No matter how much I try to change the margins or padding, nothing moves. When I get the body and page somewhat okay, the navbar is how it's supposed to be. It's as if a white line always appears above or on the side of the navbar.

I don't everything about coding, so I can't say I tried everything. But here is my CSS code.

```
body{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav{
background: #5a5a5a;
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

label.logo{
color: white;
font-size: 26px;
line-height: 80px;
padding: 0 100px;
font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul {
float: right;
margin-right: 20px;
}
nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
line-height: 80px;
margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
color: white;
font-size: 17px;
padding: 7px 13px;
border-radius: 3px;
text-transform: capitalize;
}

.containerA {
background: #fff;
display:flex;
width: 900px;
align-items: center;
margin: 30px 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
}

\#containerB {
background: #fff;
display: inline-block;
width: 900px;
text-align: center;
margin: 30px 50px;
padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: What is this selector `\#containerB` supposed to be?

Comment: Could you post your actual issue that you want solving and a screenshot possibly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.